# NTP - debugging weird offset stats

Tags: debugging, offset, ntp

**Setup**

I have a setup with 2 routers acting like NTP servers for an NTP client (Meinberg NTP) installed on a test server on the network. I have been synchronizing with both servers but after experiencing weird behavior, I switched to only use a single NTP server to synchronize with to be able to debug a problem I seem to have.

It seems, that the offset varies a hole lot during the day and it has values between (+10ms and -150ms). This is way off and much much more than the required values for our setup wich is a few ms a maximum.

**Screenshots of statistics**

I have configured the NTP Client to drop log files with statistics and then I have used a graphical dot print tool to create some graphs of the offset, jitter etc. over time. The following shows the average time of the logfile for today:

[image]
*Overview statistics*

Following are the offset graph, the delay, dispersion and the jitter graphs:

[image]
*Offset*

[image]
*Delay*

[image]
*Dispersion*

[image]
*Jitter*

**My observations**

It seems that four times today there have been some remarkable spikes on the graphs. And each time a spike has occured, that offset seems to be in sync, hitting a very few ms offset. But then it seems to be drifting away again.

The NTP Client has been running for a week, so I would expect any initial calibrations to be done.

Does anyone have the abilities to point out some obvious reasons for this behavior?

Thankyou in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out, that the NTP servers I was synchronizing with, had delayed responses depending on the load on the servers. After correcting this to have a higher priority for the NTP servers, the problem was gone.